# Full site chat on iOS 11 and iPad Pro 10.5 breaks at the bottom of the page

Tags: bug, chat, safari, ios

Using the native Safari browser with no content blockers or user scripts, the bottom of the screen tap targets are generally messed up in landscape mode on the iPad Pro 10.5 running iOS 11.

- Help, FAQ, legal, privacy policy and mobile links are all not tappable.
- Tapping in the chat window next to your icon does not bring up a keyboard.
- Dragging up from the chat window text entry section does scroll content so the touch events are getting registered, just that tap to enter text is getting swallowed up somehow.
- If you tap slightly above the text entry field - the keyboard engages correctly if you do not have a smart keyboard active.
- If you tap slightly above the text entry files - the keyboard engages improperly if you have a smart keyboard attached. Improper means the text entry cursor is flashing above the text entry field - approximately where you need to tap in the first place to bring up the keyboard (and not where you *should* tap, but where it's active).
- Typing is correct without smart keyboard - typing is incorrectly overlaid when you have a smart keyboard.

I can upload a video if this isn't easily reproduced by the development team on shipping iOS 11.

[image]

It's not broken on the same build of iOS 11 on the iPhone 7. It's only broken in landscape mode, not in portrait orientation.

Mobile Safari on iOS 11.0 (15A372) through iOS 11.1 is affected. Chrome and FireFox browsers on iPad Pro 10.5 (size of iPad Pro - not the iOS version) are also affected.

Comment: I assume this is a report for the mobile web UI, not the app? If so, is this in Safari or another browser?

Comment: Full site ui running on mobile safari - you can see the image attached. Video is only needed to show the typed text being rendered up over the yellow hilighted area. Should be easy for someone to reproduce all the links bottom right that are broken and untappable.

Comment: @AdamLear same for Chrome & Firefox. I have iPad Pro 10.5” and can confirm almost completely unusability of chat in full web mode. Looks like there is something Y shift: you need to tap any UI item slightly above to interact with it.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @alexolut - could it be as simple as hard coded screen sizes and the smaller bezel / larger size of the 10.5 is causing the offset?

Comment: @bmike I don’t know. It worked well before updating to iOS 11. After reading your post I can use it in portrait mode at least.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know on which side the fix was made, but now I noticed that the problem is gone. Currently I’m using same iPad Pro 10.5” with iOS 11.4.

Tested on Safari and Chrome.